# Are there any advantages of using Testng with cucumber?

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, testng

When creating automated tests with selenium, I thought one would use easier cucumber with selenium or testng with selenium or just junit with selenium although using only junit is not very popular. I have recently found out that you could use cucumber with testng but I don't see what is the gain of doing this. If someone is using both of them together can you tell me why ?

EDIT:
Using Testng over junit has many advantages. My question is if i use cucumber does it still make a difference or not anymore.

P.S I am not trying to start this tool vs this tool war

Comment: I am not able to understand question. you want to compare Cucumber+JUnit to Cucumber+TestNG or Cucumber to TestNG or JUnit. ?

Comment: @GaurangShah Cucumber+JUnit to Cucumber+TestNG

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348984/cucumber-junit-vs-cucumber-testng

Comment: @GaurangShah the question in link is not answered

Answer (score 4):

The answer that you seem to be looking for, is one of interest in what Cucumber, as a tool, adds to existing test frameworks.

The answer:

Cucumber adds an extra level of communication between you (the development team) and the management team. You are able to link test cases to scenarios that are now understandable by the business, which means that everybody is on the same page. You can even use the BDD tool to start talking about behaviours of the feature:

- What things should be included?
- Do we need more information?

Lets add that to the file, so that we can test that use case later.

- Any new functionality added to the feature later?
- Need to understand which section has gone wrong quickly, without having to decipher code written by the intern that was in for 2 months in the summer?

Cucumber helps with all of this, and that's just scraping the surface.

TestNG, JUnit, Selenium? You imagine it, you can do it. With Cucumber as your helpful neighbourhood BDD tool, you can pull together your test suite and bolt an abstraction layer on top. The business will now be able to look at the test results. Where tests have failed, they will be able to describe exactly what section has gone wrong to other members of management, without having to go too far into technical details.

If you're wondering whether to use JUnit or TestNG for this, it is most likely to be your choice. Using whatever is the current test tool to bolt cucumber on top of is the best option if you have an existing suite.

Also, make sure you are using the right language for your team. For instance:

- Are you introducing a team of manual testers to developing test automation?
  Maybe you should use Ruby or JavaScript, as they are easier languages to pick up as a first language
- Are you a development team, using cucumber to add an abstraction layer to your unit tests?
  Use the language that you are using for development, with the unit test tool that you are using.
- Are you developers in test, using cucumber for automating tests for your website?
  Use the language that you and your team are most comfortable with, taking the language being used for development over any others that tie with this (based on a team vote).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree 100% that introducing Cucmber has a huge benefit and I am already using it,  My question was about if i am already using cucumber what is the difference between testng and junit but it seems that it doesnt make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what are your other tests (unit ones for example) and how you run them.

If your current tests are already using TestNG, then it will be easier to run Cucumber tests with TestNG engine.

At the opposite, if you already have JUnit tests, it could be easier to use JUnit for Cucumber run (but TestNG is able to run JUnit tests, so you can use TestNG in that case too).

And if you have no other tests, so the choice of the test runner will depend on your own taste.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, if you already have a project and want to add cucumber. But what i am interested in is in the case of starting a new project. I know that without cucumber testng is much better than junit (there are many comparisons if you google it), and what I wanted to know if there is a difference if I am using cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. I understand your question. Even I had the same doubt as below:
 We use selenium for automation testing. Since they don't provide proper reports, we add TestNG to it (and also for other features). But now, we have cucumber, which gives proper reports. So why do we need TestNG?

I realized, though we get proper results with cucumber, TestNG provides us with many other features which cucumber cannot; like setting priority, setting method dependency, timeouts, grouping , etc.

Though cucumber provides a tag feature, it does not provide all the features provided by TestNG. Maybe when cucumber incorporates all those features, we can eliminate TestNG.